# Displaying a grid as 2 parts in java

Tags: java, swing

I have a grid that is 100 square boxes. For the purposes of the program this is the same grid however for visual purposes I need to have a label through the middle of it.

I know I can declare 2 separate grids and add 2 separate panels but this would be rather annoying rework of everything just for visual purposes . I am hoping there is a way to display the first 50 boxes in 1 panel on top and add a second panel to display the other 50 boxes.

I should be more specific this is done in a GUI swing frame, not an actual print to console.

So as a summary

Current grid:

```
[][][][][]
[][][][][]
```

Desired grid:

```
[][][][][]
  LABEL
[][][][][]
```

Comment: I should be more specific this is done in a GUI swing frame, not an actual print to console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `JFrame` with a `BorderLayout`.

1. In the BorderLayout.PAGE_START you add a panel with one grid
2. In the BorderLayout.CENTER you add the label
3. In the BorderLayout.PAGE_END you add the second panel.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use a BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: yes but I want to keep it to only 1 grid is there any way to say in 1 panel show indexes  1-50 and 51-100 in second?

Comment: Why not? You can do whatever you want. You can write a loop from 0- 99 to create 100 objects or you can create two loops. Once from 0 - 49 and the second from 50 - 99. I not sure what your concern is?

Comment: you were correct I figured it out with some layouts thanks.